# Class loading exception [org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException]

Tags: hibernate, apache-tomee, openejb, tomee-7

I am getting following exception when starting the tomEE server, hibernate and openejb version that I am using  is 5.2 and  7.0.1 respectively.

In `persistence.xml`, I have given  all the entries for required classes. As well in the War file I can see corresponding class for which we are getting class not found exception. I could see some related issues in the following link, do you see any version compatibility issue with the versions that I am using.

[integration test with openejb container and hibernate fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168943/integration-test-with-openejb-container-and-hibernate-fails)

```
SEVERE: Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/adminmgmt-web] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: C:\servers\tomee\enterprise-server-dozer-2.0.0-20161003.201205-21\webapps[\adminmgmt-web: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.admin.transportation.core.model.TaskInstance]: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.admin.transportation.core.model.TaskInstance]
at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1039)
at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:717)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1257)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1115)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5076)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1405)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1395)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)              
 caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.admin.transportation.core.model.TaskInstance]: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.admin.transportation.core.model.TaskInstance]
at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:870)
... 13 more
```

Answer (score 0):

the link looks like another issue, can you share your setup (which libraries in WEB-INF/lib, where is persistence.xml, what is its content) and maybe a sample cause I have some apps working with 5.2.3.Final of hibernate.

Also note that for tomee snapshot (if you want to try) you need to set

```
<property name="tomee.jpa.factory.lazy" value="true"/>
```

in your persistence.xml cause of hibernate lifecycle